I am trying to add xml file resource folder in MAUI app, but it's always showing file not found error when i try to use this in c# code
I am trying to add xml file resource (raw folder) folder in MAUI app,
but it's always showing file not found error when i try to read the file in code behind
is there any procedure to add raw files in Maui Project
below is the code what i try ( i am getting runtime error "file not foud")
    async Task LoadMauiAsset()
    {
        using var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("AboutAssets.xml");
        using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

        var contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }


Did you set Build action of your file to MauiAsset?

yes Build action is done in file properties

It's weird, I test the code you provide and it works well, you can see this.

Yes it's working, after some time , i think it happen to me for some build issue

i try this for face detection with cascade xml file but no luck, link

Have you tried to use other xml file to test?
